# How to synchronize password with macbook safari and iphone3gs safari?

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I would like to use the password generated by my macbook safari while I am using my iPhone 3gs safari...

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to sync Safari passwords with an iPhone 3GS. iCloud Keychain syncing requires iOS7, which in turn requires an iPhone 4 or later.